# echo out $_SESSION data

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I have a bunch of data in an array which has been collected in a session. I am able to print_r this and show all the contents but I am struggling to show the product name, id, image etc.

I am showing the using:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

It prints out everything I need but not in the format I require. So I know it is collecting my data and storing it in the array. I have set the data in another files like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['product_img'][] = $_POST['product_img'];
    $_SESSION['product_id'][] = $_POST['product_id'];
    $_SESSION['product_name'][] = $_POST['product_name'];
    $_SESSION['product_price'][] = $_POST['product_price'];
    $_SESSION['product_sku'][] = $_POST['product_sku'];
    $_SESSION['product_description'][] = $_POST['product_description'];
}
```

And it is all of the above I want to output.

Comment: remove the [] at the end of of each $_SESSION variable.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you're trying to do. As far as I can tell, you're asking how to output the data in a "readable" format, while print_r is pretty readable to me.

Comment: Sorry, so for example i need to show the product image, the product name as I would when selecting these items form the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Either you stick with your proposal : `$_SESSION['...'][]` **

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['product_img'][] = $_POST['product_img'];
    $_SESSION['product_id'][] = $_POST['product_id'];
    $_SESSION['product_name'][] = $_POST['product_name'];
    $_SESSION['product_price'][] = $_POST['product_price'];
    $_SESSION['product_sku'][] = $_POST['product_sku'];
    $_SESSION['product_description'][] = $_POST['product_description'];
}
```

and format it like so:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $elements)
{
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        echo $element . '<br />';
    }
}
```

**Or use this other method:**

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['product_img'] = $_POST['product_img'];
    $_SESSION['product_id'] = $_POST['product_id'];
    $_SESSION['product_name'] = $_POST['product_name'];
    $_SESSION['product_price'] = $_POST['product_price'];
    $_SESSION['product_sku'] = $_POST['product_sku'];
    $_SESSION['product_description'] = $_POST['product_description'];
}
```

and format it like so:

```
foreach($_SESSION as $element)
{
    echo $element . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: But my question is really how I do output this data in a readable format?

Comment: By Remove the `[ ]` it stops me having the ability to add multiple items to the session

Comment: By using a foreach I get `Array Array Array Array Array Array`

Comment: Yes, then you use another foreach on those arrays. :P

Comment: Im really sorry I don't follow this is something I am really struggling with.

Comment: @Ivan Not true. If you do `$_SESSION['something'][] = $var` it will add `$var` to that *two-dimentional* array with the next available index PHP chooses - this is valid PHP (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying for an example). And because they are dual arrays, you need something like `foreach ($_SESSION as $arr) { foreach ($arr as $value) { echo $value."<br />"; } }`

Comment: Yes, I realised this when testing it

Comment: @Qirel Ahhh we seem to be a little closer

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to output this as HTML is to use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, which goes through each item in the array.

To make things easier, I would suggest changing your POST code so that each item is a single array, like so.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['products'][] = array(
        'img' => $_POST['product_img'],
        'id' => $_POST['product_id'],
        'name' => $_POST['product_name'],
        'price' => $_POST['product_price'],
        'sku' => $_POST['product_sku'],
        'description' => $_POST['product_description']
    );
}
```

Now you can iterate through `$_SESSION['products']` and get the information for each product in the session. For example:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product) {
    $name = $product['name'];
    $id = $product['id'];
    $price = $product['price'];
    $img = $product['img'];
    $sku = $product['sku'];
    $description = $product['description'];

    echo "<h1>Product: $name</h1>";
    echo "<p>Price: $price | ID: $id</p>";
    echo "<img src='$img'>";
    echo "<p>$description</p>";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: This method is far cleaner